# Written as disjuctions, conjunctions and negations?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

With a domain from -2 to 2 I'm trying to write the following using disjunctions conjunctions and nagations. I'm not sure how correct I am and wanted to know if I did them correct? Could someone help with the last one I just cant figure out how to start that expression?

> $∀ x\ P(x) = P(-2) ∧ P(-1) ∧ P(0) ∧ P(1) ∧ P(2)$
>
> $\neg ∀x\ P(x) = (P(−2)∨P(−1)∨P(0)∨P(1)∨P(2))∧¬(P(−2)∧P(−1)∧P(0)∧P(1)∧P(2))
>   In English doesn't that mean: At least one element is true and one element is false?
>
> $∃x\ \neg P(x) = $

**Edit:** The last two with the correct answer of "At least one is not true".

> ∃x￢P(x) = ￢P(-2) ∨￢P(-1) ∨￢P(0) ∨￢P(1) ∨￢P(2)
>
> ￢∀xP(x) = ￢(P(-2) ∧ P(-1) ∧ P(0) ∧ P(1) ∧ P(2))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last two should have the same answer, since the second one, $\lnot\forall x.P(x)$ says that it is not true that $P(x)$ holds for every $x$, while the third one, $\exists c.\lnot P(x)$ says that there exists an $x$ for which $P(x)$ does not hold.  These mean exactly the same thing. "Not every crow is black" is the same as "There is a crow that is not black."

But your answer for the second one is not correct.

Mouse over for hint:

> $\lnot\forall x.P(x)$ says that it is *not* true that every element of the domain satisfies $P$.  But $P(-2)\lor P(-1)\lor\ldots\lor P(2)$ says that $P(x)$ *is* true for -2, or for -1, or…

**EDIT**: Now your second one is correct, if you and I have the same idea for the part you indicated by "…", but it could be much simpler.

**EDIT**: Now your second one is incorrect again. $\lnot\forall x.P(x)$ says that $P(x)$ is not true for *every* $x$. It does $not$ say that $P(x)$ is true for any $x$; it might be false for all $x$.

Comment: I was thinking could I just do a simple statement such as P(x) AND !P(x) thus saying that at least one has to be true and false?

Comment: Nothing can ever be both true *and* false.

Comment: Sorry I was thinking of all 5 elements in the domain as a group. (P(−2)∨P(−1)∨P(0)∨P(1)∨P(2))∧¬(P(−2)∨P(−1)∨P(0)∨P(1)∨P(2))

Comment: Nothing, including your  
big disjunction $(P(−2)∨P(−1)∨P(0)∨P(1)∨P(2))$, can ever be both true *and* false.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to change the signs on the negation to be ands (P(−2)∨P(−1)∨P(0)∨P(1)∨P(2))∧¬(P(−2)∧P(−1)∧P(0)∧P(1)∧P(2)) In English doesn't that mean: At least one element is true and one element is false?

Comment: What you just said is correct. But that is not what $\lnot\forall x.P(x)$ means.  $\lnot\forall x.P(x)$ says that they are *not all* true. It does not say that any of them *are* true. For example, not all cows are purple.

Comment: Oh I was always thinking that one of them had to be true. So really the simple answer is ¬(P(−2)∧P(−1)∧P(0)∧P(1)∧P(2)). As long as they are not all true it is true.

Comment: Right! ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2):

If the domain $\Omega$ is finite, then 
$$\Big(\forall x\in\Omega\ \ P(x)\Big) \iff \left(\bigwedge_{x\in\Omega}P(x)\right)$$
and
$$\Big(\exists x\in\Omega\ \ P(x)\Big) \iff \left(\bigvee_{x\in\Omega}P(x)\right)$$
assuming that the alternative of zero elements is false and conjunction of zero terms is true. In old books $\bigvee$ and $\bigwedge$ denote just the regular quantifiers $\exists$ and $\forall$ respectively, here the symbols are used as big (indexed) alternative and conjunction in a fashion similar to sums $\sum$ and products $\prod$.

Also this somehow explains the [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) for quantifiers:

$$\neg \forall x\ P(x) \iff \neg \bigwedge_x P(x) \iff \bigvee_x \neg P(x) \iff \exists x\ \neg P(x),$$
$$\neg \exists x\ P(x) \iff \neg \bigvee_x P(x) \iff \bigwedge_x \neg P(x) \iff \forall x\ \neg P(x),$$

just because
$$\neg\Big(P(x_1) \land P(x_2) \land P(x_3) \land \ldots\Big) \iff
\Big(\neg P(x_1) \lor \neg P(x_2) \lor \neg P(x_3) \lor \ldots \Big),$$
$$\neg\Big(P(x_1) \lor P(x_2) \lor P(x_3) \lor \ldots\Big) \iff
\Big(\neg P(x_1) \land \neg P(x_2) \land \neg P(x_3) \land \ldots \Big).$$

Those are just hints, but I hope it helps ;-)